# How can I set the project signing certificate to None?

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I set the signing certificate to `None`? I see some open source projects were able to set their **Signing Certificate** to the value **None* to let other developers build the app freely.

[image: Signing Certificate with value None]

Here is an open source project which has **Signing Certificate** set for different purpose to value **None**.

[image: Signing Certificate with value None]

**Update**

The status shows I need "Signing for 'MyAppName' requires a development team".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check **Automatically manage signing**.

[image: "Automatically manage signing" checked]

---

2. Select **None** for the team.

[image: "None" option selected for the team]

---

3. Uncheck **Automatically manage signing**.

[image: "Automatically manage signing" unchecked]

Comment: thanks, @the4kman. I could not build the app if I choose team "None" (see updated question). I got it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Change `Code Signing Identity` to `Don't Code Sign` will solve the issue.

[image]